# Get Data from Cursor in Android

Tags: java, android

My Code to Iterate Over a Cursor

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {                                                                 
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {                                                           
    String x  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("event_name"));                  
    System.out.println("Cursor ::::::" + x);                                            
    listViewModel.setEventDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("event_date")));  
    modelList.add(listViewModel);                                                       
}
```

}

SYSO prints:

```
Cursor ::::::android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{2e1dacdf VFED..CL ........ 0,73-1344,209 #7f0c006f app:id/eventName}
```

Cursor to Get Data from Db:

```
 public Cursor getEvents(Domain dbOperations){
    database = dbOperations.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {TableInfo.TableDetails.EVENT_NAME, TableInfo.TableDetails.EVENT_DATE};
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT event_name, event_date FROM events", null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Can Someone help me to get what exactly is there in the Database?
Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're saving the return of an `EditText#toString()` call to the database. It should be `EditText#getText()#toString()`. Also, your `while` loop is skipping the first record in the `Cursor`. Use a `do-while` instead.

Comment: Thanks Mike. That's exactly what I was doing..!! Thanks for the suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are inserting to database:

```
contentValues.put("event_name", eventNameEditText.getText().toString());
```

Also you should change the loop:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {                                                                  
do {                                                            
    String x  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("event_name"));                  
    System.out.println("Cursor ::::::" + x);                                            
    listViewModel.setEventDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("event_date")));   
    modelList.add(listViewModel);                                                        
}while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

It's because of when you call `moveToFirst()` method the cursor is ready to return data from row#0. When you call `moveToNext()` immediately, it goes to row#1 and the first row is skipped.